# cannot return initial state of products in component - Redux

Tags: redux

While I have an array of items as initialState:

```
export default {
  cart: [],
  products: [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Redux",
        price: 100000
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "React",
        price: 0
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Redux DevTools",
        price: 10
      }
]
}
```

I am accessing it through products-reducer:

```
import initialState from './initialState.js';


export default function products(state = initialState.products, action){
     return state;
};
```

and the Products component which maps a list of products through the products-reducer :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addToCart } from '../actions/cart-actions.js';

class Products extends Component {

  render() {

    const productList = this.props.products.map( (item,index)  => {
      return <div key={index}>
        <p style={{ color: "#767676"}}>{item.name} - {item.price} $ </p>
        <button className="button"
                onClick={() => this.props.addToCart(item)}>
          Add To Cart
        </button>
      </div>
    });

    return (
      <div className= "products">
         { productList }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        products: state.products
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        addToCart: item => dispatch(addToCart(item))
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Products);
```

I am not able to load the product list using the component `<Product />`. Can someone help me why it will not show the list of products (of initialState.products) even though I use mapToStateProps and connect the products with state.products that will contain the initialState of them in the Product component?

Comment: i don't see anywhere you actually export the Product class?

Comment: I'd put a debugger on the first line in render to inspect if products is correctly mapped to component; Just add "debugger;" to first line

Comment: @WenHaoWu if you see the last line of Products component there is export default connect...

Comment: Like Hanming said, add a console.log(this.props.products) under render() to see if you have thing there.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you are using `initialState.products` to initialize the state. Then in your component `mapStateToProps` you are accessing `state.products` but your state is already the `products` itself. So to fix this just do:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        products: state
        // instead of products: state.products
    };
}
```

So basically what you are doing currently is trying to access `initialState.products.products`. I hope I explained myself properly.

Comment: That's an interesting comment, so when i tried what you proposed it was showing the error "this.props.products.map" is not a function and after reverting to the previous  ```products: state.products``` it was finally loading the products..

Comment: I guess then you have a root reducer that has a products field, this way you would be able to do `state.products` properly. Well I am glad one way or the other I helped =D

Comment: Yes you are right, i didn't include this file ```const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    cart,
    products,
});             export default rootReducer;```